# Add a span in nav top meu

Tags: topmenu

I want to add a `span` in `nav top menu` after every `li`. Also in this `span` I want to add an image (arrow-down).

I added this code in `top.html` but nothing show!!!

```
<span class="arrow"><img src="Pictures/arr-lft-ico.png"/></span>
```

How can I add a span in top menu?

This is the code of `top.html`:

```
<?php $_menu = $this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(0, 'level-top', 'sub-wrapper' ) ?>
<?php if($_menu): ?>
<nav class="olegnax">
    <ul id="nav">
        <?php if (Mage::getStoreConfig('celebritysettings/celebritysettings_header/navigation_home')): ?>
         <li class="level0 level-top">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?>">
                <span><?php echo $this->__('Home'); ?></span>               
            </a>
         </li>
     <?php endif; ?>
        <?php
        echo $_menu;
        $custom_tab = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load('celebrity_navigation_block');
        if($custom_tab->getIsActive()) {
            echo '
            <li class="level0 level-top parent custom-block">
                <a href="#" class="level-top">
                    <span>'.$custom_tab->getTitle().'</span>                    
                </a>
                <div class="sub-wrapper">'.$this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('celebrity_navigation_block')->toHtml().'</div>
            </li>';
        }
        ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add after anchor tag

You need Menu > (like this right)

Comment: can you tell me I should add what and where in `top.html` ?

Comment: <li class="level0 level-top">
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?>">
                <span><?php echo $this->__('Home'); ?></span>               
            </a><span class="arrow"><img src="Pictures/arr-lft-ico.png"/></span>
         </li>